# PHP: Getting variables form config.cfg with given structure

Tags: php, config

it's probably a silly question for a pro, but even after hours of googleing I could not find a solution:

I have a shared config.cfg with the following structure (so I can't do anything about the structure):

```
[config]
fileExtensions="JPEG|JPG|jpg|jpeg|png|gif"
contentFolder="Gallery"

[images]
maxSize=1900
jpegQuality=85

[thumbnails]
jpegQuality=80
blurredImageQuality=3
```

I managed to get the config.cfg into my php script and can call some variable, for example 'maxSize'. Now comes the but:

My current solution just loads the config.cfg as a simple array:

```
Array ( [fileExtensions] => JPEG|JPG|jpg|jpeg|png|gif [contentFolder] => Gallery [sortOrder] => asc [titleDescSeparator] => $$ [albumCoverDetector] => @@@@@ [ignoreDetector] => _hidden [maxSize] => 1900 [jpegQuality] => 80 [blurredImageQuality] => 3 [allowedSizeValues] => 50|100|225|150|200|300|auto [allowOrigins] => * )
```

But to get a variable which is twice in the config.cfg, I need to load the config-file including the structure (with array and sub-arrays). Anybody has an idea how to do this? Heres my current code:

```
<?php
$config_values = parse_ini_file('./nano_photos_provider2.cfg');
print_r($config_values); //call whole array
echo $config_values[maxSize]; //call single variable
?>
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) that you should **read first** there's a second argument which is:

> By setting the process_sections parameter to TRUE, you get a multidimensional array, with the section names and settings included.

So, you just need to:

```
$config_values = parse_ini_file('./nano_photos_provider2.cfg', true);
print_r($config_values); //call whole array
echo $config_values['images']['maxSize']; //call single variable
```

Comment: If answer helps - feel free to __accept__ it. It raises your reputation also.